# Adding facebook comments to my website object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way I can create comments related to my object, without using the comments plugin? The Facebook Graph API seems like the correct way, but can I link to an object on my web site without actually "posting" that object as a post on facebook? Amazingly, I can't find anyone on the Net with this problem, so perhaps I'm simply doing it wrong.

I'm trying to post to:

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://iesgroup.ca/myappbeta/Item/1799633&message=test&access_token....

I do have the publish_stream permission in the access_token. All I get back is "An unknown error has occurred".

Essentially, I have set up my own web site using the Open Graph protocols. Each item that I have has its own URL with the proper OG tags. For each item, I am able to fetch the comments that facebook has associated with it. But I am unable to actually attach new comments to that object, without using the facebook comment plugin. I'm using my own look-and-feel commenting system, so I am not interested in using facebook's module. I'm using the JavaScript API to fetch the existing comments.

Note, that if I use the Open Graph protocol, users are able to post actions to their timeline, but not actually associate new comments to the object.

Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to use the Facebook Graph API and have a Facebook website application and use server-side code to directly re-post comments from your website to the facebook page on an existing Facebook object.  It is much more in-depth than the simple Open Graph implementation.  But if you don't want to use Facebook's comment module, I don't see any other option.  This is a link to the area of making comments, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/ , but this is only useful after you have everything else set up.  This is a huge undertaking to get your website to this point, but you will have full control over every aspect of how you interact with Facebook, cause you write your own code.  Here is a link to the top level of the FB Graph API so you can read more about it. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Nick - www.meltedjoystick.com

Comment: Thanks Nick. That is how we have the web site set up; yes, it took awhile. It's a full open graph implementation. But for each object we have set up, while we can read the comments on it, we cannot post comments onto it.

Comment: You'll notice that in the first link you gave it talks about adding a comment to a Post. But we don't have a post, we just have an object on our site that has a URL ID.

Comment: From what I know of the FB Graph API, you can only post comments on posts made by your facebook application.  So your app needs to make those posts you want to make comments on.  Sorry.

Comment: Nick you're probably right (as frustrating as that is), but do you know of any documentation that actually states that limitation?